# Value at position 2 in the NgModule.imports of AdminModule is not a reference Value could not be determined statically

Tags: angular

Hello programmers I have this error after update the angular/cli and the angular/core.

```js
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { AdminComponent } from "./admin.component";
import { AuthComponent } from "./auth.components";


let routing = RouterModule.forChild
([
    { path: "auth", component: AuthComponent },
    { path: "main", component: AdminComponent },
    { path: "**", redirectTo: "auth" }
]);

  @NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule, routing],
    declarations: [AuthComponent,AdminComponent]
  })
  export class AdminModule
  {

  }
```

This is what I have installed

> Angular CLI: 11.2.9 Node: 14.15.4 OS: win32 x64
>
> Angular: 11.2.10 ... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core,
> forms ... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router Ivy
> Workspace: Yes
>
> Package                         Version
> --------------------------------------------------------- @angular-devkit/architect       0.1102.9 @angular-devkit/build-angular
> 0.1102.9 @angular-devkit/core            11.2.9 @angular-devkit/schematics      11.2.9 @angular/cli
> 11.2.9 @schematics/angular             11.2.9 @schematics/update              0.1102.9 rxjs                            6.6.7 typescript                      4.0.7